# What does this compiler error regarding statics in a class template mean?

Tags: c++, templates, static

I was playing around with class templates and statics and saw this:

```
template<int I>
struct rat
{
    static bool k;
};

bool rat<3>::k = 0; //this is line 84 of the only source file play.cpp

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    rat<3> r;
}
```

compiler error:
play.cpp:84: error: too few template-parameter-lists

I thought when I said rat<3>::k i was instantiating that template and defining the static for that particular template and thus the use of `rat<3>` would be fine from there on..how come this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be

```
template<>
bool rat<3>::k = 0;
```

but better use `false` for `bool` then `0` since it's more readable

Also in case you want to make you variable initialized for all templates as `true` for example:

```
template<int I>
bool rat<I>::k = true;
```

And you can still specialize template for `I = 3`:

```
template<>
bool rat<3>::k = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the template:

```
template<>
bool rat<3>::k = 0;
```

And *of course* MSVS accepts your syntax (but not if I turn off language extensions).